# In magento 2 how can i give discount to product if particular category's product exist in cart?

Tags: magento2, cart, customer, discount

In Magento 2 I am want to give a 15% display to the product which do not exist in the "member" category but in cart must be 1 product available which is from the "member" category. and customers must be login into their accounts.

3rd condition is customer must not have member number in there account. for member number i have created custom field in registration form and stored into admin so if customer do not have member number then i will give 15% discount.

**Example:** In cart, we have 2 product "A" and "B"

Product "A" is added into the "member" category.
Product "B" is not added to the "member" category.

Now I want to give a 15% discount to product "B" if Product "A" exists in the cart.

I have written code in the "**checkout_cart_product_add_after**" event my code is partially working after login.

**Scenario 1:** if I will add first Product "A" which is from the "member" category and then if I will add Product "B" I can see a 15% discount in the cart to product "b".

**Scenario 2:** If I will add Product "B" first and then if I will add Product "A"  then my code is not working customer is not getting a 15% discount.

I have written the below code in the observer.

```
    if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
    
    // retrieve quote items collection
    $itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
    
    // get array of all items what can be display directly
    $itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    
    // retrieve quote items array
    $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    $ids = array();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $productid = $item->getProductId();
        $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productid);
        $categoriesIds = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
        foreach($categoriesIds as $categoryId){
            $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
           $id = $cat->getId();
             if($id == '12')
           { 
       
                $ids = '12';
           }
        }
    }
                    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');           
                    $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
                    $product = $item->getProduct();
                    $attributeval = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('exclude_membership')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
                    $exclude_from_15_discount = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('exclude_from_15_discount')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
                    //$logger->debug($attributeval); 
                    //$subtotal = $item->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
                    //$membersubtotal=$subtotal*100/10;
                    //exclude_from_15_discount
                    if($ids == "181")
                    {
                        if($exclude_from_15_discount == "No"){                  
                            $price=$item->getPrice();
                            $finalprice=$price -$price*15/100;
                            $item->setCustomPrice($finalprice);
                            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($finalprice);
                            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                            
                        }   
                }
    
    }
```

So please let me know how can I resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure about the code, however I think you can solve this use cart rules. I tested it on clean Magento installation and it works fine, the key is to use “Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions”:

I created 2 products.

Product A – Price: 50

Placed in in a category called member (id=41)

Product B – Price 100

So, idea is:

If a product is from the Member category and customer is logged in

Then give 15% discount on the other products in cart (not in the Member category)

(1) Create a new cart rule

(2) Select the Customer Group of your logged in users:

[image]

(3) Set Conditions and Actions:

[image]

The result is this:

[image]

Hopefully you can use cart rules. Notice here that adding Product A, activated the 15% discount on product B.

Comment: this will not work you have given 15% of to subtotal 150 i just want to give 15% of to Product "B" which i not in member category. and this 15% should work if Product "A" available in cart otherwise it  will not working. so in your example only 15% work for so $50 so 50-7.5 = 42.5 + 100 = subotal should be 142.5 

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hmm. wait a bit. You want to give 15% discount on product B. Product B cost 100. 100*15 = 15, which is the discount I am giving.

Comment: If I would give 15% discount of the subtotal of 150, it would have been 150*15% = 22.5